# Matrix representation of the differentiation map with respect to the basis $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

$B = \{{x^2 - 1}, {2x^2 + x - 3}, {3x^2 + x -3}\}$

Find the matrix representation of the differentiation map $D: P_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R}), P(x) \rightarrow P'(x)$ with respect to the basis $B$.

So I showed that B is a bases for $P_2$. I'm fairly certain this matrix representation shouldn't be difficult, but what exactly will it end up looking like?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a linear map $T$ and an *ordered* basis $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, then to find the matrix of $T$ in $B$ you need to first calculate $Tb_1,\ldots,Tb_n$ and express them as linear combinations of $b_1,\ldots,b_n$.

The coefficients of those will be the columns of the matrix of $T$ in $B$.

If you can show that $B$ is a basis, I'm sure you can do the other steps by yourself, too.

Answer (score 0):

First note that your matrix is going to be $3\times 3$ because $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $3$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}.$ A differentiation map is a linear operator (as I'm sure you've proved before). To find exactly which linear operator is it, you just apply it to the basis vectors, i.e. $x^2 - 1, 2x^2 + x-3,$ and $3x^2 + x -3.$ After doing that, write each of the resulting "vectors" as a linear combination of the three basis vectors - the coefficients of each will give you the elements of a column in the matrix representing differentiation.

Comment: So I'm still a little confused. Do I take the derivative of the 3 vectors in B? Then what?

Comment: are the  columns (-6, 0, 2), (-13, -1, 5), and (-19, -1, 7) or am I way off? I think I did it correctly.

Comment: that looks fine to me